# U-Boot defconfig common configuration

Tags: config, u-boot, kbuild

I was in the middle of adding a new board to Yocto while I noticed that a lot of the configuration could be inherited from the previous hw revision.

So I was wondering if there could be the possibility of including a `common_defconfig` in the `<new_board>_defconfig` to not duplicate all the configuration files. Similarly to what happens with `dts` files.

E.g.

common_defconfig:

```
CONFIG_ARM=y
CONFIG_SPL=y
CONFIG_CMD_I2C=y
```

board_hw1_defconfig:

```
#include "common_defconfig"
CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD_HW1=y
```

board_hw2_defconfig:

```
#include "common_defconfig"
CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD_HW2=y
```

### UPDATE 1

Like pointed out by @Xypron, and as I was suspecting, there is no way to include different `_defconfig` one in another.

I also tried to create a generic `Kconfig.defconfig` to select some configurations. The problem was that, for example, `ARM` is defined as a `config` inside a `choice` so cannot be selected from inside a `Kconf` file.

I will end up creating a `do_configure_append` task where I will merge the `_defconfig` files through the use of `scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh` if no one will come with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

U-Boot inherits the build system from Linux. Neither of both support includes in *_defconfig*-files up to now. If you want it changed you need to come up with a patch for scripts/kconfig/Makefile *scripts/kconfig/Makefile*.

The *configs/*defconfig* files are seeding *.config*. So anyway most of the configuration comes from presets in the *Kconfig* files. This is different to the device trees where for ARM systems all values come from **.dts* and **.dtsi* files.